# Problems building OpenSSL 1.1.1c using gcc version 4.3.3

Tags: c, gcc, openssl

I'm trying to compile the OpenSSL 1.1.1c project in a toolchain which uses `gcc 4.3.3`
After finishing the configurations and issuing `make` the following error messages are shown:

```
crypto/sha/keccak1600-armv4.S: Assembler messages:
crypto/sha/keccak1600-armv4.S:2203: Error: ']' expected -- `vst1.64 {q4},[r0:64]'
crypto/sha/keccak1600-armv4.S:2205: Error: ']' expected -- `vst1.64 {d18},[r1:64]'
crypto/sha/keccak1600-armv4.S:2248: Error: ']' expected -- `vld1.64 {q4},[r0:64]'
crypto/sha/keccak1600-armv4.S:2251: Error: ']' expected -- `vld1.64 {d18},[r1:64]'
crypto/sha/keccak1600-armv4.S:2326: Error: ']' expected -- `vst1.64 {q13},[r0:64]'
crypto/sha/keccak1600-armv4.S:2347: Error: ']' expected -- `vld1.64 d25,[r2:64]!'
...
```

I assume the problem is because of the low version of gcc which I am using. 
I didn't find any explanations about the minimum required gcc version in the [OpenSSL Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation).

How can I solve this error?

Is the problem from the gcc version?

Comment: Since the errors are specifically the assembly files, I would guess the problem is actually your Perl installation. OpenSSL uses perl to preprocess the assembly code. Do you have at least perl 5.10? There isn't a minimum C compiler version, as far as I know, it just needs to be ANSI compliant.

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez My perl version is 5.22.1 and your right, I just found out that the assembly file is generated by a perl script.

Comment: Any update on this? Were you able to figure out the problem?

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez Yes, I found out the problem was from the perl script which was generating the assembly file. I fixed it on my own fork of Open SSL and made a pull request. You can see the changes I made in this link: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/9518/files I believe the problem was from the new syntax of the assembly files or it might be a typo.

Comment: Nice, that's great. I don't think the OpenSSL team is going to accept the change as "trivial" though. At the very least I think it's going to require an update to the documentation to point out that ARM builds require the change in syntax. Trivial commits are basically just typos, I think. This is all speculation; I'm not a committer, so this could be 100% wrong, but I'm guessing that's what the comments on the commit are going to be. Specifically, I think they're going to want you to submit a CLA, which is not a big deal, but it will hold up the merge until they have that, for legal reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the assembler was unable to recognize this syntax.

After taking a look at other generated assembly files in the OpenSSL project, I found some lines of assembly code which were written in the same syntax with an additional comma(,) before the colons(:). So I went back to the main code and after changing the pointed lines by adding a comma before the colons, I had been able to get a successful build.
I checked this change to see if it doesn't result in any misbehaves at the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317021/6826476

I have also made a pull request to get a confirmation from the OpenSSL community and it got accepted:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/9518#pullrequestreview-274502366