# ARM assembly syntax in VST/VLD commands

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm using the `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` toolchain to build a project which involves linking some assembly files together.

One of the assembly files contains multiple commands as this:

```
vst1.64 {q4}, [r0:64]        @offload A[0..1][4]
```

As far as I know, according to the [ARM Assembler Reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/ch05s145.html) the command is suppose to store the contents of register q4 in a part of a memory which is aligned by 64 bits and the text after the At-sign is just a comment. However, when I want to build the project the below message is given:

```
Error: ']' expected -- `vst1.64 {q4},[r0:64]'
```

Which means there is some sort of syntax error.
After modifying the line as below the error is gone:

```
vst1.64 {q4}, [r0,:64]        @offload A[0..1][4]
```

I wanted to know if this modification causes the line to do some thing different or not. Is there any other way to fix this error?

Comment: an assembly language is defined by the assembler, the tool, not the target. so what the exact syntax is can vary by assembler.you are using the gnu assembler, famous for changing syntax from a processor vendors syntax, but using arm documentation for the assembler reference, you are crossing the streams.  sometimes you can "just" cause a compiler (same toolchain as the assembler) to generate the code and run with that, or generate the machine code and disassemble (.word 0x12345678 assemble then disassemble). the disassembler on gnu doesnt necessarily match the syntax for the assembler directly

Comment: what does the machine code look like and how does it compare to the arm documentation for the thing you want to do?

Comment: You just fixed it. The comma was missing. `[r0:64]` is simply wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fix seems correct. The correct syntax for alignment does contain the comma, but some versions of binutils do support leaving out the comma as well. There's no difference in meaning between the two, just different strictness of the parser. Both assemble into the exact same instruction.

GNU binutils 2.25 and 2.30 seem to accept both forms.

```
$ cat test.s
        .text
        .syntax unified
        vst1.64 {q4}, [r0:64]
        vst1.64 {q4}, [r0,:64]
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -c test.s -o test.o -mfpu=neon
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   f4008adf        vst1.64 {d8-d9}, [r0 :64]
   4:   f4008adf        vst1.64 {d8-d9}, [r0 :64]
```

Comment: Just to be sure. Did it execute in the same way or did it just compile and build?

Comment: no need to execute examine the machine code for the two different ways.

Comment: Yes, both assemble to the same exact instruction.